# How can we beat Prince of Gluttons in Aeon's End

Tags: aeons-end

Been playing a bit more of Aeon's End base game, so far, the only nemesis that we simply can't beat with a team of two is the Prince of Gluttons.

We never manage to beat him, whatever the spells/relics/gems, we just get overwhelmed by his minions and his base power. We tried buying only things he devoured, but usually, that's not enough. We do not manage to get geared early enough, Gravehold gets beaten hard, we somehow stale (or die) then he eats everything and we loose.

We had some trouble with the Crooked Mask, but we managed with it, it was a *very* close game, but it felt "fair". The Prince beats us with no trouble, we have trouble to survive, and he has a time limit...

What can we do to beat him? Are there specific compositions to have? Do we need to buy expansion packs to get better/other mages/cards?

Comment: For the close votes, I think this is not too broad since I ask for tips contained in the base game, there is a finite number of spells/relics/gems, so there *should* have a way to beat it in the base game, and a reliable tip that apply most of the time

Comment: Once you start including all the different expansions as you have also asked about it can become a lot more broad.

Comment: @JoeW I'm not asking what extension would help to beat him, but if we *need* to buy them in order to beat him

Comment: That is still the same thing as you need to know which ones would help beat the nemesis in order to know you need to buy it

Comment: The thing is, if it's not *needed* and that he's indeed beatable with only base game components, it's a valid answer. I could even settle for a "you really need lot of luck and you need spell A  and B to be available and devoured in the first turns" as a tip, I just want to know if he's beatable with base content + tips if there is some.

Comment: If it is a base nemesis it is beatable by the base set. Now you might need more than 2 players to beat it or you might be using the wrong characters (also might have the wrong market setup). The problem is in general this is a very hard and unforgiving game where a single mistake can take a certain victory away. When you start to consider Number of players, Number of expansions available and market setup the number of variables starts to grow pretty large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do we need to buy expansion packs to get better/other mages/cards?

No. You do not need to buy expansion packs.

> Are there specific compositions to have?

No. You can win with any random mages and a random supply from the base set.

> What can we do to beat him?

1. Build a lean deck with heavy hitter spells and don't gain weak cards from the supply in the late game.
2. When gaining cards from the supply, don't reduce any pile to zero. Empty piles help Prince of Gluttons.
3. Let Prince of Gluttons devour cards that you want. Gain them from his devoured pile.
4. It can be strategic to leave spells prepped for two reasons 1) more gems in hand 2) you need spells up when a minion is drawn.
5. Plan to discard Power Cards. More often than not it is worth it.

Answer (score -1):

Any tips to beat him?
-Great work gaining cards that were devoured. That helps.

-Consider that when you gain any cards from the supply you help the Prince. How much damage can you do based on minimal card buys? For instance, buy ONLY ONE gem like Searing Ruby for the whole game. Now, how can you set up a hand to be that Ruby + 4 Crystals? Because 7 aether can buy any spell in the game. Now you're cooking.

-Consider player health and Gravehold's health as a just another resource you're spending. If players and Gravehold are at full health but you lose because Prince devoured the store then maybe you were being overprotective. Take some trade offs, absorb more damage and focus on preventing devours and dealing damage on the Prince.

-If you're losing because of Devours than defensive mages like Brama (heal player health) and Phaedraxa (prevent damage) don't have abilities that help. Better to choose attackers like Jian and Kadir and win during Tier 2.

-You know the cards. You know what's coming. What are you keeping prepped to crush Cerephage?

Specific compositions to have? Do we need to buy expansion packs to get better/other mages/cards?

-No. My partner and I have played an embarrassing amount. We have no trouble against the Prince with randomly chosen mages and supply.

Soft advice for new players.

-You'll get it with more playing/experimenting.

-Look at high cost cards that don't seem worth it. The design team is smart. Challenge yourself to think about why those strange cards are so valuable. You'll unlock another insight to help.

-This is a game about efficiency. You want to play 'tight' where nothing is wasted. I often see new players love opening breaches (because it's rad) without any spells to prep. Having 1 aether left over that you do nothing with is like a tiny bit of damage to the team.

-How's your development? Your decks start wimpy, start to grow, then at least one player should be ready to drop bombs. The minions are a decent measuring stick. If a minion, like Tier 2 Venomite (9) appears then at least one player should be reasonably positioned to deal out at least 9 damage in the round.

-The endgame is often a 'boss rush'. All players need to agree it's time to go all in on damaging the boss, absorbing damage from nemesis cards.

-For practice, if you're playing 2 or 3 player, put more Tier 1 and Tier 2 cards in the nemesis deck. This is how we got our first victories many battles ago. It will make the game a bit easier but still give you a lot of practice.

-Experiment by playing a battle where you ALWAYS prevent a nemesis Power card.

Sorry for the long answer :) I hope this finds a player who finds it useful. Needless to say, we've really enjoyed this game.